# Fetching Records from One table and making difference from same table gives irregular output

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want the sum from these two tables but I am getting seperately -

```
SELECT 
    GrandTotal - RecPayAmount - 
       (
       select 
            sum(detail.LineAmount) 
       From 
            TranPOSDetail as detail 
       where 
            detail.RefHeaderCode = TranPOSHeader.Code 
       and 
            EntryFlag = 4
       ) 
from TranPOSHeader 
where 
     VoucherTypeCode=2000 
And 
     WalkInCustomerCode=200429 
And 
     GrandTotal > RecPayAmount
```

My Output is Like

1) 10

2) 20

But I want it like -

1) 30

How can I modify this query to reflect the results I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without changing the existing query, you can try like following.

```
SELECT SUM(T.S) AS Total FROM
(
    SELECT 
        (GrandTotal - RecPayAmount - 
           (
           select 
                sum(detail.LineAmount) 
           From 
                TranPOSDetail as detail 
           where 
                detail.RefHeaderCode = TranPOSHeader.Code 
           and 
                EntryFlag = 4
           ) 
         ) AS S
    from TranPOSHeader 
    where 
         VoucherTypeCode=2000 
    And 
         WalkInCustomerCode=200429 
    And 
         GrandTotal > RecPayAmount 
) T
```

Comment: Ya i am.. but its telling me to accept answer after 2 minutes... i will accept dont worry.

Answer (score 1):

Use Cte and aggregate total values

```
 WITH Amount
    AS (
        SELECT GrandTotal - RecPayAmount - (
                SELECT sum(detail.LineAmount)
                FROM TranPOSDetail AS detail
                WHERE detail.RefHeaderCode = TranPOSHeader.Code
                    AND EntryFlag = 4
                ) TotalAmount
        FROM TranPOSHeader
        WHERE VoucherTypeCode = 2000
            AND WalkInCustomerCode = 200429
            AND GrandTotal > RecPayAmount
        )
    SELECT Sum(TotalAmount)
    FROM Amount
```

Comment: yup its working... thanks for your time.. can you vote my post ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one simpler approach

```
SELECT Sum(GrandTotal - RecPayAmount - oa.Total_LineAmount)
FROM   TranPOSHeader th
       OUTER APPLY (SELECT Sum(d.LineAmount)
                    FROM   TranPOSDetail AS d
                    WHERE  d.RefHeaderCode = th.Code
                           AND d.EntryFlag = 4) oa (Total_LineAmount)
WHERE  VoucherTypeCode = 2000
       AND WalkInCustomerCode = 200429
       AND GrandTotal > RecPayAmount
```

Comment: yup its working... thanks for your time.. can you vote my post ?